# When page is minimized horizontally, inline div overflow, and it does not auto-reduce horizontally, and scroll x appears

Tags: html, css

I want to make the code compatible with all screens. When I press restore down on the PC screen, Chrome browser, to reduce the width of the screen, the inline div elements are not minimized and scroll x occurs, How can I make the inline div automatically minimized  without using media tag meaning that I want
All  inline  div are automatically reduced as the screen width is reduced

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;


}
body{
background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606625736768-f521ab7e23fb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=jeswin-thomas-PtfRiBumfQU-unsplash.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: wheat;
background-size: 1400px;

}


.logodiv{

    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid white 3px;
     margin: 30%;
     margin-top: 10%;
     margin-left: 40%;
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
}
.logoimg{
width:200px ;
margin-left: 25px;
height: 200px;
}

.headertextdiv{
width: 450px;
height: 300px;
/*background-color: blue;*/
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: -300px;
}
#headerh1{
color : white;
text-align: center;
}
#headerp{
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}
#headerlink{
    margin-left: 35%;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
text-decoration: underline;
font-style: oblique;
}
.fixeddiv{
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
margin-top: -140px;
margin-left: -5px;


}
.headerlist{
display: inline-block;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
padding-left: 45px;
font-weight: bolder;

padding-inline: 30px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 50px;
}
 a:hover{
color: blue;
}

.menu1flexdiv{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.315);
width: 80%;
height: 1200px;
margin-top: 150px;
margin-left: 100px;
display: flex;
}
.imagediv{
padding-top: 100px;
}
#img1menu{

    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;

    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px; 
}
#imgmenu{

display: block;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
#h2pmenu{
color: white;
font-weight: bolder;
}
.menudiv{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.textmenu{
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
height: 900px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding-top: 100px;
padding-left: 100px;
}
#tablemenudata1{

color: black;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}
#tablemenudata2{

    color: rgb(5, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    max-width: 200px;
    }

**html code :
**
    hr{

width: 250px;
color: black;
margin-left: 0px;
    }

html code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='test6.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fixeddiv">
    <div>
<a class="headerlist" href="">Home</a>
<a class="headerlist" href="">menu</a>
<a class="headerlist" href="">our story</a>
<a class="headerlist" href="">contact us</a>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="logodiv">
        <img src="1.png" class="logoimg">
    </div>
    <div class="headertextdiv">
<h1 id="headerh1">Stunning food, Amazing Quaility</h1>
<p id="headerp">Let us host your next special occassion
</p>
<a href="call:111-111-111" id="headerlink">Contact US today</a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu1flexdiv">
<div class="imagediv">
<img src="2.jpg" id="img1menu">
<img src="3.jpg" id="imgmenu">
</div>
<div class="menudiv">
<h2 id="h2pmenu">DRINK MENU</h2>
<p id="h2pmenu">Sprits, wine, and beer</p>
<div class="textmenu">
    <table>
<tr>
    <td id="tablemenudata1">Vodka 1oz</td>
    <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
</tr>
<tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
    VODKA and choice of juice or soda.
</td>
</tr>

    </table>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tablemenudata1">Vodka 1oz</td>
            <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
            VODKA and choice of juice or soda.
        </td>
        </tr>
        
            </table>
            <hr><table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="tablemenudata1">Rum 1oz</td>
                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                    RUM and choice of juice or soda.
                </td>
                </tr>
                
                    </table>
                    <hr><table>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="tablemenudata1">Whisky 1oz.</td>
                            <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                            Whisky and choice of juice or soda.
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                            </table>
                            <hr><table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">Vodka 1oz</td>
                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                    VODKA and choice of juice or soda.
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                    </table>
                                    <hr><table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">Tequila 1oz.</td>
                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                            Tequila served with juice or soda.
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                            </table>
                                            <hr><table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">Red wine.</td>
                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$8 </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                    8oz Red wine, ask server for our wine selection.
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                                    </table>
                                                    <hr><table>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">White wine.</td>
                                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">$8 </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                          <span>  8oz white wine, ask server for our wine selection.</span>
                                                        </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        
                                                            </table>
                                                            <hr><table>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">Sparkling wine .</td>
                                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                                    8oz sparking wine glass of your choice.
                                                                </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    <hr>
</div>


</div>
   </div>
   <!--الجزء التاني من المنيو-->
   <div class="menu1flexdiv">
    <div class="imagediv">
    <img src="4.jpg" id="img1menu">
    <img src="5.jpg" id="imgmenu">
    </div>
    <div class="menudiv">
    <h2 id="h2pmenu">FOOD MENU
    </h2>
    <p id="h2pmenu">Entrees, mains, and handhelds
    </p>
    <div class="textmenu">
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tablemenudata1">Nachos</td>
        <td id="tablemenudata1" style="padding-left: 30px;">$12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
        cheese, onions, tomotoes.
    </td>
    </tr>
    
        </table>
        <hr>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="tablemenudata1">Tacos</td>
                <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                chicken or beef with your choice of side.
            </td>
            </tr>
            
                </table>
                <hr><table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tablemenudata1">Chicken rice bowl.</td>
                        <td id="tablemenudata1">$16 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                        brown rice, and veggies, served with choice or sauce
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                        </table>
                        <hr><table>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="tablemenudata1">Grilled chicken</td>
                                <td id="tablemenudata1">$15 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                Juicy grilled chicken served with choice of sauce.
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                                </table>
                                <hr><table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tablemenudata1">Vodka 1oz</td>
                                        <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                        VODKA and choice of juice or soda.
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                        </table>
                                        <hr><table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td id="tablemenudata1">Steak and fired beans.</td>
                                                <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                Steak and your choice of side.
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            
                                                </table>
                                                <hr><table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td id="tablemenudata1">Red wine.</td>
                                                        <td id="tablemenudata1">$8 </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                        8oz Red wine, ask server for our wine selection.
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    
                                                        </table>
                                                        <hr><table>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td id="tablemenudata1">burrito.</td>
                                                                <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                              <span>  Your choice of beef or chicken.
                                                            </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            
                                                                </table>
                                                                
                                                                        <hr>
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
       </div>
       <!--الجزء التالت من المنيو-->
       <div class="menu1flexdiv">
        <div class="imagediv">
        <img src="6.jpg" id="img1menu">
        <img src="7.jpg" id="imgmenu">
        </div>
        <div class="menudiv">
        <h2 id="h2pmenu">DESERT MENU
</h2>
        <p id="h2pmenu">Deserts and sweets
</p>
        <div class="textmenu">
            <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tablemenudata1">Chocolate cake .</td>
            <td id="tablemenudata1">$7 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
Loaded Chocolate cake with fudge topping.
        </td>
        </tr>
        
            </table>
            <hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="tablemenudata1">NY cheesecake.</td>
                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                    NY cheesecake toped with strawberry topping.
                </td>
                </tr>
                
                    </table>
                    <hr><table>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="tablemenudata1">Apple pie.</td>
                            <td id="tablemenudata1">$6 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                            Warm apple pie tooped with icecream.
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        
                            </table>
                            <hr><table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">Churros.</td>
                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$7 </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                    pancake mix, water, oil, sugar, cinnamon.
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                    </table>
                                    <hr><table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">Sopaipillas</td>
                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">$7 </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                            Light, crispy pastry puffs, sopaipillas are a sweet way to round out a spicy meal.
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                            </table>
                                            <hr><table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">Creamy Caramel Flan.</td>
                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                    A small slice of this impressively rich, creamy, caramel flan dessert goes a long way.
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                                    </table>
                                                    <hr><table>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">Shortcut Tres Leches Cake</td>
                                                            <td id="tablemenudata1">$12 </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                            My mom's favorite cake is tres leches, a butter cake soaked in three kinds of milk.
                                                        </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        
                                                            </table>
                                                            <hr><table>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1" style="width: 200px;">Pressure-Cooker Pumpkin Flans</td>
                                                                    <td id="tablemenudata1">$14 </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr><td id="tablemenudata2">
                                                                  <span> This silky, smooth dessert captures the essence and elegance of fall.</span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    <hr>
        </div>
        
        
        </div>
           </div>
</body>
</html>



try using word warping or left or right tag
```

Comment: You need to add your html codes as well. Currently, I can't see it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to post a [reprex] for people to work with. In the mean time... you are using *Absolute length units* instead of *relative length units*. Suppose you downsize to a screen of 360x720px, what do you think will happen e.g. using `.headertextdiv { width: 450px; ... }`?

Comment: sorry html code has been added after css

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).